# Getting attribute from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I made an object to manage the candidate education in online marketplace

```
let education ={
    tabs:{},
    render:function(){
        document.querySelector('#education-tabs').innerHTML = ''
        let container =``;
        Object.values(this.tabs).map((tab)=>{
            container += `
            <div class="education-tab-container">
                <div class="education-tab-right">
                    <div class="big-title">   
                        ${tab.faculty}
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-title">
                        ${tab.department}
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-title">
                        ${tab.university}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="education-tab-left">
                    <div class="date">
                        ${tab.from || ''} ${tab.to || ''}
                    </div>
                    <div class="close" data-id="${tab.id}">
                        <span>x</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        })
        document.querySelector('#education-tabs').innerHTML = container
    },
    deleteTab:function(id){
        delete this.tabs[id];
        this.render();
    },
    add:async function(payload){
        this.tabs = {...this.tabs,[payload.id]:payload}
        this.render();
    }
}
```

This updates the UI every time I add a new tab to this object.
The problem is when I try to remove a tab: sometimes I get the data-id attribute of the tab that I made and sometimes it returns null.

here is my function

```
const triggerListener = ()=>{
    $("#education-tabs").find(".education-tab-left .close").click((e)=>{
        if(e.target.getAttribute('data-id')){
            alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
        }
    });
```

so is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should make sure, that every tab has `id` when you add it. I would check `payload` for `payload.id` before adding it, because `{ null: {/*some data*/}}` - is legit structure.

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing